# Comparing references in Java

Tags: java

Let's say that you have overridden an object's equals() and hashCode() methods, so that they use the object's fields.

How you do you check if two references are to the same object, ala the stock equals() method?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `==` on objects to perform identity comparison.

That is what the default implementation of `equals()` does, but one normally overrides `equals()` to serve as an "equivalent content" check.

Comment: Also, most equals operations perform the this == obj check, because obviously if they are referencing the same object, then equals will return true (assuming equals works :))

Answer (score 6):

That's what the == operator does.

Answer (score 2):

The default bahaviour of equals() is to compare the two objects using the == operator. So if you want the default bahaviour use ==, if you want your overridden behaviour use equals().

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this for JUnit Assertion, you can also use `Assert.assertSame()`

Answer (score -1):

use == Operator because it compares with the reference not with the content,
if u want to compare with content u can use equals() method.

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of the existing answers.